# Datagrid from Contentplace holder aspx page, Form is on Master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is asp.net application in VB. I have a master page and it has several contenet place holders have child pages. I have datagrid on those child or sub pages. I am trying to export these ASP:datagrids to excel. I know we have good examples of doing this. I am using following method:

```
    Dim excelFileName As String = "Filename" + "_" + Date.Today + ".xlsx"
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + excelFileName)
    Dim stringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim textWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
    dgrid.RenderControl(textWriter)
    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString())
    Response.End()
```

My problem is I am not able to do it because it says that for using this code the grid and button should be under  tag with property runat=Server. My trials were.

1. Tried to add this grid to form using form.control.add(dGrid). It did not let me as I have <% %> code restriction. Which is requirement so I can not get rid of it.
2. Use Bind() method after datagrid is loaded, which ofcourse give me no values on excel.
3. Tried to use master page to findcontrol on run time from the loaded page. But still it says should be under  tag with property runat=Server.

So Question Is : how to use the master page  tag at the child (in Contentplaceholder)

Comment: resolved 1. Used ASP:GridView on contentplaceholder view. 2. directCast the masterpageform in contentplaceholder page's code. 3. explicitly redirected master page form to contentplaceholder code and used the above code on button click. This atleast solved my purpose so thought to share with you guys. Thanks for your view